# passing all array items using a for loop

Tags: android

am trying to pass the array items so that they can be displayed as image views but facing difficulty in implementing it. any help.

class sampleData.java

```
public static ArrayList<Data> generateSampleData() {
int sampleData[] = {
       R.drawable.imageone,
       R.drawable.imagetwo,
       R.drawable.imagethree

};
String repeat = " repeat";
final ArrayList<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>();
for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT; i++) {
    Data data = new Data();
    data.image = sampleData[0];
    data.title = "Pinterest Card";
    data.description = "Super awesome description";
    Random ran = new Random();
    int x = ran.nextInt(i + SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT);
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        data.description += repeat;
    datas.add(data);
}
return datas;
```

class Data.java

```
 public class Data {

    public int image;
    public String title;
    public String description;

    public Data() {}

}
```

> here is the error am getting if i change data.image = sampleData[0] to
>   data.image = sampleData[i]

```
06-19 11:51:02.814    1626-1626/com.richapps.true_gamer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
            at com.richapps.true_gamer.grid.SampleData.generateSampleData(SampleData.java:21)
            at com.richapps.true_gamer.FindPeopleFragment.onCreateView(FindPeopleFragment.java:29)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What difficulty are you facing? A sytax error, an exception? If you can tell, it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: What are you trying to implement brother? Can you talk us through your idea?

Comment: that code displays only the same picture in a grid view. i want to display all the pictures in the array differently in a gridview

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
data.image = sampleData[0];
```

to

```
data.image = sampleData[i];
```

Comment: forces close when i run it

Comment: It is probably because of something else in your code. Share your crash report please.

Answer (score 0):

you have a 0 in your brackets. That means you print the same image on every row. Change it to your loop letter which is 'i'

```
data.image = sampleData[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

got it working.

Initially i had set SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT=10 but when i set it to 4 it worked because it had to match with the number of items in the array. Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: replace `SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT` with `sampleData.length()` in `for loop's` condition

Answer (score 0):

As your `sampleData[]` has 3 items and `SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT's` value is 10 while you try to access `data.image = sampleData[i];` got [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) when `i is greater than 2` so change this

```
for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT; i++) {
    Data data = new Data();
    data.image = sampleData[0];
    data.title = "Pinterest Card";
    data.description = "Super awesome description";
    Random ran = new Random();
    int x = ran.nextInt(i + SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT);
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        data.description += repeat;
    datas.add(data);
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < sampleData.length(); i++){
    Data data = new Data();
    data.image = sampleData[i];
    data.title = "Pinterest Card";
    data.description = "Super awesome description";
    Random ran = new Random();
    int x = ran.nextInt(i + SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT);
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        data.description += repeat;
    datas.add(data);
}
```